# PHP: Invalid character breaks html

Tags: php, character-encoding

how should I clean up a string which contains invalid characters and would break html after printing it in textarea?

PHP's `ord()` returns 0 for the said character, but I suspect it's not null, which I don't think it matters anyway.

When string is displayed in textarea all text after the invalid character would disappear as well as all html elements after the textarea.

I tried with `htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars`, `mb_convert_encoding`, `iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str)`, but neither of them worked.

`filter_var()` isn't introduced yet in 5.1.2 which we are using.

echo and var_dump print the character as �

Comment: We ended up using multibyte regular expression function which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try `filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW)`.

**Edit:** Since 5.1.2 doesn't have filter_var, you could try this (which is almost the same thing):

```
preg_replace('/\p{Cc}/u', '', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but we are using 5.1.2 which doesn't feature filter_var() yet.

Comment: I think they have a PECL version of the filter extension for 5.1, but I've added another answer to the post anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I have used this regular expression before when htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, mb_convert_encoding, iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str) didn't work.
It strips out the control characters

```
$str = preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/', '', $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
$str = trim($str, chr(0));
```

??